# Function returning a pointer instead of a value in Python

Tags: python, pointers

I've done a function to generate a list of passwords, but it returns a pointer instead of a value:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import string
from random import *

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def generator():
    password =  "".join(choice(characters) for x_num in range(randint(18, 19)))
    return password


def pass_list(num_of_passwd):
    paswd_list = []
    for index in range(num_of_passwd):
        paswd_list.append(generator())
    passwords = pass_list
    print (passwords)
```

why is this happening?

Comment: What is it returning? Where is the output? What do you mean my returning pointer?

Comment: Nm, I misread too. `passwords = pass_list` is a typo. You mean `passwords = paswd_list`. That assignment is pointless btw, you could just do `print(paswd_list)`

Comment: we don't use the term "pointer" in python. There are various explanations about how to think about python variables. If have a C background, every non-primitive variable in Python (a list in non-primitive) is a reference (or 'pointer'). Python only ever passes values. When the value is a reference, the language dereferences it as needed. So you can pass a list as a parameter, and then change the parent value in the called function, as you would expect when passing pointers. But you can't do that for a number. And strings are "primitives" in Python.

Comment: @TimRichardson I don't really follow that. You can change a global mutable object in a function but you can't change an immutable object. That's it. It's about name-lookup and scopes. I'm not sure what you're trying to say; a string is immutable - changing it in a function scope requires a re-binding to a name. In any case, this is a typo

Comment: @roganjosh when someone posts a Python question and talks about "pointers", there is (I guess) little point talking about 'global mutable objects'. I guessed the OP is coming from a C/C++ background. Anyway, what I said is 100% correct. String is immutable, because Python treats it as a "primitive" type. This is a big difference to C, which I why I mentioned it. There is so much mumbo-jumbo about Python typing, but it boils down to what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, string, random

def generator(chars):
    password = "".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(random.randint(18, 19)))
    return password

def pass_list(chars, num_of_passwd):
    pass_list = [generator(chars) for _ in range(num_of_passwd)]
    return pass_list

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
passwords = pass_list(characters, len(characters))
print(passwords)
```

**Output:**

```
['R63qhL4pzkwyb4DxyJ', 'iStYwujZ9hbGhKhCvr', 'CawJ3qAdqSL0Bf8phZ', '48PPQj8btdxaqshDkk', '318rubpkcR5mOrPMYOT', 'iOkINL0TkjL4sq9Mc3', 'Fw64Tj5KyNVNbJRYLD', 'voALiyI3vn70F3H7Ua6', 'ofAGywZqrEMcJkRwjWL', 'wMlYVakjZzz6Sm04jcv', 'PbPT2Hr9nR0eLhX0aKj', 'Fqa3oGBFj4HmdJR8C3', 'Wva99eZyXZZHaKrwrlT', 'kC7kRHuDYx9njsttQG', 'r5IQZF61lLRowiXQ6e9', 'Lh50xONU63ftvNUoAY', 'ByaxlBt8qVB9RbdQZz', 'b6VNghr4mhT4wfNGec', 'UB3qnHHdEF9OEvk5BHc', 'yA3j7sH4oClb5EybDN', 'E9ejvelWBUFVWCfAKL', 'ladx1niGhZv8bGoghY', 'E2EerTp7sMN6VBAV7Q', 'IxELC2nB5f4zCinvjK', 'DqF38rzrcihfFJwCJN', 'YeakZZHZKRAIM3Bt1pE', 'oJrLBQhyepaF1LiBfZJ', 'gNsgLR9Berqowg6CII', 'hLldZQ9MqxYySQ9Kti', 'mzGE71SiVHqdIbxDMwh', 'qkfAXnEWUkkxPTvaL3', 'FUx1xoKGFpDSM1SB8A', '0vH3AePPLAmbJonqTP3', 'thf80WN1JK4WdtrEySk', '9GlqeSobGMND6LzqYU', 'CqPPeqyAjM1YVjiN3UF', 'gdAHZdIxYSgdBCRli3', 'i2ltodn3npecEjV6bXu', 'ejSBXWalzp6QvQFzuE', 'usnv3Wwb4drwX6KUIkg', 'f24RszgtS8KyNE3A8u', 'lVYyoQoR9QVmUC4F7M', '5avz5UvQqMjC2oCPCCs', '1yVSXljlVqx83pCuPdo', 'sUkmkR2Otb89YFPtRQ', 'sVOnTTVBhr3ss6JjFi', 'o3ZIR1aRd579G6YPrBI', 'PP1WxXisQqYfB0OSYz', 'o6qcvRrAOqJDvf5HxB', 'UlrdaaIR3QVU8haF3qn', 'MrfKJcbNq4GjuPUPkNF', 'vU3aWCQFSpAVzZBp5E', 'ZzpLG4bqLrjENf8Uv6t', 'cy15Fqtw9rCKoOtCuN', 'Y7Iwjr9BjoDcMuz9l9', 'hsdc6B45lgtgsbD5fux', 'uZPp7buh4faAJSymD4V', 'u15I7Jy8hhCXRhGdEL', 'wucZvSYhQ3du5gR0H6', 'W1lzh3kSmDB8ZJyEGX', 'UkEE85JGJvhbNhbS8RM', 'oZiqjgW5GfCstWf09Hb']
```

---

**Problems with original code:**

1. `pass_list()` was not actually called in the script.
2. Appended to an empty list rather than using comprehension - drastically slower.

**What changed:**

1. Cleaner syntax (in general) - for example when looping over a variable which is not used anywhere it is better to use "_" in my opinion.
2. Function call at the end to produce your results.
3. list comprehension to replace appending for loop.

Comment: You can choose how many passwords to generate using the second argument of `pass_list()`

Comment: While providing a copy-paste-able solution is OK, it would also help the OP if you can explain what was wrong with the original code, and how your code fixed it.

Comment: @GinoMempin Thanks for the suggestion, check the edit.

Comment: Thanks! I really like the `char` option, and it works!